# How to Update Layout for a Flutter app with Backdrop as a main app menu

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I’m totally new to Flutter so please accept my apology for a stupid question( probably it is stupid). My question is if implemented backdrop for my app menu would I be able to update any certain screen with new one. For example, if I was on android with an app home screen with a backdrop, after clicking upon a menu I would show a fragment, and after some interactions with it from the user, I would have shown a different fragment depending on the design and app flow. My question is what would I do in Flutter for updating a screen rather than using MaterialPageRoute for changing the entire screen.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, maybe try to clear it up a bit. Just ask what you want to do. Also, from my attempt at understanding, I think you want to replace the current screen? Is that it? For that you can try to use `Navigator.pushReplacement` method. If its something else, maybe try using an example, as its a little hard to understand what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PageView` widget if you don't want to use `Navigator`.

```
PageController _pageController;
int _page = 0; // initial page index

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _pageController = PageController(keepPage: true);
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _pageController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

void onPageChanged(int value) {
  setState(() {
    this._page = value;
  });
}

void go(int index) {
  _pageController.jumpToPage(index); //this will change the current page in view.
}
```

And go to your Backdrop Widget and modify as follows.

```
backLayer: Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      ListTile(
        title: Text("Screen two"),
        onTap: () {
          go(1); //page index
        },
      ),
      ListTile(
        title: Text("Screen three"),
        onTap: () {
          go(2);
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
),


frontLayer: Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: PageView(
    onPageChanged: onPageChanged, //page changed function
    controller: _pageController, //controller
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //disable swipe
    children: <Widget>[
      HelloScreen(), //put your screens here.
      ScreenTwo(),
      ScreenThree(),
    ],
  ),
),
```